# Apache spark : Reading & replacing Database from xml files or Json

Tags: java, sql-server, json, xml, apache-spark

I am using Apache Spark 1.3.0 with MS SQLServer 2012. Database is very big and while loading that in RDDs during server startup takes lot of time. I am now trying to convert the Database tables to XML o JSON format and load those files in the application in RDDs format to reduce the server startup time.

SQL Server directly supports conversion of tables to XML so my preference is XML.

Is there any way we can load XMLs to RDD format in Apache Spark through Java API?

If anybody knows the answer, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom input format class by  extending TextInputFormat.class in hadoop, later you can use the xmlInputFormat to parse the file and get the key value out of the xml file.

```
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.set("xmlTag.end", "</"+"book"+">");
    JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Text> file1=context.newAPIHadoopFile("/user/zeas/niharTest/book.xml",XmlInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class,config);
```

The xmlinputformat i have written in java is given below. Here "book" in the parent tag for the xml file.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class XmlInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext tac) {

        return new XmlRecordReader();

    }

    public static class XmlRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
        private byte[] endTag;
        private long start;
        private long end;
        private FSDataInputStream fsin;
        private DataOutputBuffer buffer = new DataOutputBuffer();
        private LongWritable key = new LongWritable();
        private Text value = new Text();
        private static final String END_TAG_KEY = "xmlTag.end";
        public static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(XmlRecordReader.class);
        private int startElement = 0;

        /*
         * public XmlRecordReader(String currentValue) {
         * this.START_TAG_KEY=currentValue;
         * this.END_TAG_KEY=START_TAG_KEY.replace("<", "</");
         * 
         * }
         */

        public XmlRecordReader() {
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(InputSplit is, TaskAttemptContext tac) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) is;

            endTag = tac.getConfiguration().get(END_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");
            start = fileSplit.getStart();
            end = start + fileSplit.getLength();
            Path file = fileSplit.getPath();

            FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(tac.getConfiguration());
            fsin = fs.open(fileSplit.getPath());

            fsin.seek(start);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            if (fsin.getPos() < end) {
                try {
                    if (readUntilMatch(endTag)) {
                        Text values = new Text();
                        values.set(buffer.getData(), 0, buffer.getLength());

                        String tempValue = values.toString();
                        if (startElement == 0 && tempValue.contains("<?") && tempValue.contains("?>")) {
                            String element = new String(endTag, "utf-8").replace("</", "<");
                            try {
                                element = element.replace(">", " ");
                                tempValue = tempValue.substring(tempValue.indexOf(element), tempValue.length());
                            } catch (Exception e1) {
                                element = element.trim();
                                tempValue = tempValue.substring(tempValue.indexOf(element), tempValue.length());
                            }
                        }
                        startElement++;
                        try {
                            XmlParser parser = new XmlParser(tempValue);
                            String str = parser.getValue().trim();
                            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 2);
                            value.set(str);
                            key.set(fsin.getPos());
                        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                } finally {
                    buffer.reset();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return value;

        }

        @Override
        public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return (fsin.getPos() - start) / (float) (end - start);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            fsin.close();
        }

        private boolean readUntilMatch(byte[] match) throws IOException {
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                int b = fsin.read();

                if (b == -1)
                    return false;

                // if (withinBlock)
                buffer.write(b);

                if (b == match[i]) {
                    i++;
                    if (i >= match.length)
                        return true;
                } else
                    i = 0;
                if (i == 0 && fsin.getPos() >= end)
                    return false;
            }
        }

    }

    private static class XmlParser extends DefaultHandler {
        private StringBuilder value;
        private int tagCount;
        private String tmpValue;
        private int counts;
        private StringBuilder str;

        public XmlParser(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
            value = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(is, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                throws SAXException {
            int count = attributes.getLength();
            tagCount = 0;
            counts = 0;
            str = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String name = attributes.getQName(i);
                if (name.contains("xmlns")) {
                    continue;
                }
                String val = attributes.getValue(i).trim();
                value.append(val + ",");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            if (counts > 0) {
                tmpValue = str.toString().replaceAll("\n", "");
            }
            if (counts == 0 && tagCount > 0) {
                tmpValue = "";
            }
            counts = 0;
            value.append(tmpValue + ",");
            if (tagCount == 0) {
                value.append("" + ",");
            }
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value.toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            String tmpValues = new String(ch, start, length).trim().replaceAll(",", " ").replaceAll("\n", "");
            if (!(tmpValues.isEmpty())) {
                str.append(tmpValues);
                counts++;
            }
            tmpValue = tmpValues;
            tagCount++;

        }
    }

}
```